# Colorbox with profile pics just like ask.fm

Tags: jquery, colorbox

This is my first question hopefully i will get a repy... This site has been really usefull for me so far... I want to implement a colorbox on my website just like ask.fm... When you press ask to friends on that website a colorbox opens on which you can select from profile pics which friends to ask... I have found where i can download colorbox from but after that i have no clue how i can implement that functionality.... Any help would be greatly appriciated... Thanks in advance...

site where i found colorbox: http://colorpowered.com/colorbox/

Answer (score 1):

Well, this is a little vague. Anyway, the way you may want to go is create a page that has an anchor similar to this one:

```
<a href="#" onclick="$.fn.colorbox({href:'/remote/partial.html'}); return false">
  my colorbox popup
</a>
```

on the server side you render (or, like in the example above, go with static content) a partial html with whatever content you have in mind, e.g.

```
<form method="post" action="/remote/partial/post_data">
  ...
</form>
```

When you click the link in the first example, Colorbox will load this content into a popup with AJAX.

There are really many different ways to go about it, try skimming through various options presented on the [Colorbox home page](http://colorpowered.com/colorbox/).